# What can cause ITransaction.CommitAsync calls to take a really long time (24h)?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We’re experiencing some strange behaviour with ITransaction.CommitAsync. Sometimes the call to CommitAsync takes 24 hours to complete.

In our scenario, we read meter data from hardware devices every 5 minutes and store checkpoints in a reliable dictionary. So every 5 mins or so, the following code is run:

```
var profileCheckpoints = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, DateTime>>(StateNameProfileCheckpoints);

using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
    // Dictionary key is a device guid + device register id,
    // e.g.: 13cdaad8-9b8b-4fba-b336-e72e06c047ab-1.0.99.1.0.255
    var key = GetCheckpointKey(context);

    // checkpoint is a DateTime
    await profileCheckpoints.SetAsync(tx, key, checkpoint);

    // this call will sometimes take 24h to complete
    await tx.CommitAsync();
}
```

We’ve got multiple background tasks running in a stateful service. Each background task communicates with a single hardware device and runs the code mentioned above. All tasks use the same reliable dictionary, but only update the key specific to the device.

Some tasks run perfectly well and the CommitAsync call returns quickly. For other tasks, the CommitAsync call may suddenly take 24 hours to complete. No exception is thrown, the code continues as usual. Once this happens, all additional CommitAsync calls for this task will also take 24 hours to complete unless we restart the service.

The cluster and all applications are reported as healthy in the portal. However, when I look in Event Viewer on the different nodes I see the following warning being logged (about once every 5 secs):

```
dropping message <some guid>, Actor = Transport, Action = ‘’, fault = FABRIC_E_CONNECTION_CLOSED_BY_REMOTE_END
```

Any idea what might be the cause of this?

Comment: It's been about a year, so this method should have run about 365 times ;) 
 Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  Anything to share based on what you found?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we kinda gave up on this scenario and now store those checkpoints in Blob storage. Will try to find some time to retest.

Answer (score 0):

Is GetCheckpointKey communicating with a device? Could it be that this is taking up a thread and blocking, meaning the thread pool is getting exhausted.

Possibly clutching at straws, but the lack of await on GetCheckpointKey makes me slightly suspicious.

Comment: All communication with the device is done at the point when the code above is hit. GetCheckpointKey only contains a string.Format call to concatenate two strings to get the dictionary key. The next call (SetAsync) still runs fine and completes quickly. The CommitAsync call then hangs.